# Method to solve slightly modified lambert function

Tags: lambert-w

As an engineer, my math knowledge is not rigour and I'm trying to solve the equation:
$$
e^{-w}(w+1)=z
$$
I know that it depends on the lambert function. But, I don't know how to get the equation above to the form in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

I chucked into [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%28-w%29*%28w%2B1%29%3D0.1) and get an answer. But, I have no idea where it comes.

My attempt so far have only been multiplying it by -1:$$
\Rightarrow(-we^{-w}-e^{-w})=-z
$$

I'm not sure where to go from here. An explanation on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}e^{-w}(w+1)&=z\\-(w+1)e^{-w}&=-z\\-(w+1)e^{-(w+1)}&=-z\cdot e^{-1}\\-(w+1)&=W(-z/e)\\w&=-W(-z/e)-1\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you please add $W_k$ with $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ for completeness?